# Magento2: How to limit maximum images per product?

Tags: magento2, product-images

I want to limit 5 images per product at backend. So admin won't be able to upload more than 5 images. How can I achieve this, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When image is uploaded in the product-images section, `add:` action of `module-backend\view\adminhtml\web\js\media-uploader.js` is triggered. So we can override this file's add function to control this.

Create a module and after specifying your etc/module.xml and registration.php files

**1) Map the media-uploader.js file in your module's requirejs-config.js with your overridden file as follow.**

```
// app\code\[Namespace]\[ModuleName]\view\adminhtml\requirejs-config.js
    var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                "Magento_Backend/js/media-uploader":"[Namespace]_[ModuleName]/js/media-uploader"
            }
        }
    };
```

**2) Override the media-uploader.js component by copying it to your module and update the add function as follow.**

```
//app\code\[Namespace]\[ModuleName]\view\adminhtml\web\js\media-uploader.js
add: function (e, data) {
    var
        fileSize,
        tmpl;

    // Get the number of images already added to the product
    var numberOfImages = $('#media_gallery_content').children('.image.item:visible').length;

    // Number of new uploading images
    var uploadingImagesLength = data.originalFiles.length;

    //console.log('Total Number of images already uploaded:' + numberOfImages);
    //console.dir(data);

    if( (numberOfImages + uploadingImagesLength) > 5 ) {
        alert({
            content: $.mage.__('You cannot upload images more than 5.')
        });
    } else {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            fileSize = typeof file.size == 'undefined' ?
                $.mage.__('We could not detect a size.') :
                byteConvert(file.size);

            data.fileId = Math.random().toString(33).substr(2, 18);

            tmpl = progressTmpl({
                data: {
                    name: file.name,
                    size: fileSize,
                    id: data.fileId
                }
            });

            $(tmpl).appendTo(self.element);
        });

        $(this).fileupload('process', data).done(function () {
            data.submit();
        });
    }
},
```

in this function, you can check the number of already existing images and also all the information of images uploading in `data` object.

Or you can use other functions of this component as well to control this!

Comment: is to possible to override only the add function throught mixin ?

Comment: @クジェー Sorry friend, I am not aware of the way of only overriding only a specific function. But since we are mapping the whole js file, I think we need to move everything.

Comment: I see, I will use map instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function saveAction()
{
    /* START: Handle the max images per product */
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $images = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($data['product']['media_gallery']['images']);
    if($totalImages = count($images)) {
        $maxPhotoPerProduct = 5;
        if($totalImages > $maxPhotoPerProduct) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Max. number of images per product reached, extra images have been removed'));
        }
        $_allowedImages = array_slice($images, 0, $maxPhotoPerProduct);
        //Return the allowed images back to the $_POST
        $_POST['product']['media_gallery']['images'] = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($_allowedImages);
    }
    /* END: Handle the max images per product */
    //Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($_POST['product']['media_gallery']['images'])); exit;
    //Run standard saveAction()
    parent::saveAction();
}
```

“app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php” controller by using the syntax shown below in Mymodule config.xml file.

```
</config>
...
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sintax before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml</sintax>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
...
</config>
```

Comment: Please read my question properly. I'm asking solution for Magento2 version. :)

Comment: Hi Deeps,  do you have solution of above question?