# How to limit 5 maximum images each product in Magento2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, image, image-upload

I want to limit 5 images per product. Admin can't able to upload more than 5 images. How can I achieve this?

Comment: your try using plugin .In plugin afterSave() function and get product image and set images upload limit https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146046/magento2-how-to-limit-maximum-images-per-product

Comment: Do you have any other solution?